# Can initiate jquery dialog, but when opening get Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an ecommerce site where I allow users to add to cart via ajax. When the add to cart succeeds I show a dialog with a success message.

At some point, and I don't know when, the dialog stopped displaying.

I've done some digging and debugging, and here is what I came up with.

1. The line of code that initializes the dialog is running with no errors.

   ```
   $('#cart_popup').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
   width:600,
   show: {
       effect: "blind",
       duration: 1000
     },
     hide: {
       effect: "fade",
       duration: 1000
     }
   });
   ```
2. The actual dialog is being set up on the page.

Original Html:

```
    <div id='cart_popup'>
  <div id='ajax_cart_recs'>  </div>
   <div id='cart_content'></div>
 </div>
```

After page load:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="cart_popup" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" style="display: none; position: absolute;"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle"><span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">&nbsp;</span><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" title="Close"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">Close</span></button></div><div id="cart_popup" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block;">
  <div id="ajax_cart_recs">
</div>
   <div id="cart_content"><div id="ajax-col-main" class="full content ajax_cart"> 

  </div>

 </div>
```

3. When the user clicks add to cart, the call is being sent, and the dialog is being updated as expected.
4. When the callback gets to the line

   ```
   $('#cart_popup').dialog('open');
   ```

   it generates the following error:

   ```
   jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
   ```

I am including jquery & jquery-ui js, and jquery-ui css.

Answer (score 0):

Is this working the way you are expecting (I simulated the ajax call, see comments in code)

```js
var ajaxCall = function() {
  // simulate ajax call here,
  // trigger callBack
  $('#cart_popup').dialog('open');
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cart_popup').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 600,
    show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 1000
    }
  });

  $('#cart_content').html('<div id="ajax-col-main" class="full content ajax_cart"></div>');

  $('#add-to-cart').on('click', function(e) {
    ajaxCall();
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id='cart_popup'>
  <div id='ajax_cart_recs'></div>
  <div id='cart_content'></div>
</div>
<button id="add-to-cart">Add to Cart Simulation</button>
```

Comment: This works in this context, but when I copy to my site it doesn't.